# select then delete mysql query

Tags: mysql, join

I have a users table and it is possible for one or more users to become related. I have a column in the database called `referred` and if it has an ID in it, if that ID gets deleted from the database, then the associated users must go too.

Here is my query:

```
START TRANSACTION;
DELETE FROM users
WHERE id IN 
  ( SELECT a.id
    FROM users a 
      JOIN users b ON a.referred = b.id );
```

If I remove user `Josh Murray` with `id='1'`, anyone that matches criteria `referred='1'` must be deleted also.

Comment: DELETE FROM users
WHERE id = 1 AND referred = 1 ?

Comment: is your referred column was announced as foreign key? if yes, then simply adding on delete `cascade` option will do the job

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to create table with foreign keys with specifying action `ON DELETE` for example:

```
ALTER TABLE users
    ADD CONSTRAINT FK_REFERRED
    FOREIGN KEY (referred)
    REFERENCES users(id)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
```

So that if for example user with `ID = 4` was referencing to user with `ID = 1` and another user with `ID = 7` is referencing to the first user(`ID = 4`), when user with `ID = 1` is deleted, user with `ID = 4` will be also deleted, and user with `ID = 7` will be deleted too.

So you wouldn't bother with deleting all other 'children' nodes of the data

Comment: Thank you for your answer - works as expected and exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

will this not do ?

```
Delete from users where (id = 1 or referred = 1)
```

Comment: what about those that were referred to 1, but also were referred by others